# How to call 4 functions every 14 days

Tags: javascript, html

SetInterval will not work here as I need it to be date/time bound. I want the functions to be called on a certain date then alternate every 2 weeks regardless of page refresh.

Precision isn't so important so it doesn't matter if the user's clock is used.

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");
let div2 = document.querySelector(".div2");
let div3 = document.querySelector(".div3");
let div4 = document.querySelector(".div4");

function function1() {
    div1.style.display = "block";
    div2.style.display = "none";
    div3.style.display = "none";
    div4.style.display = "none";
}

function function2() {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "block";
    div3.style.display = "none";
    div4.style.display = "none";
}

function function3() {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "none";
    div3.style.display = "block";
    div4.style.display = "none";
}

function function4() {
    div1.style.display = "none";
    div2.style.display = "none";
    div3.style.display = "none";
    div4.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"> 1 </div>
<div class="div2"> 2 </div>
<div class="div3"> 3 </div>
<div class="div4"> 4 </div>
```

Comment: you mean changing the visualized div on every 2 Sunday ? Just get the date !

Comment: You can simplify to one function with a loop. No need for all that repetitive code.

Comment: whhat about changing year ? restart on div 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you don't want to use setInterval, but it's needed here if you want to do this without libraries. Fortunately, I have a feeling you meant setInterval with 14 days as the interval, and that's not necessary.
Here's what I would do (sorry I can't really test it before answering because that would require about a month):

```js
const startDate = new Date(x); //x is just whenever you want to start this: if you
//don't want to use a backend with a database, you'll need to hardcode this in the javascript

window.setInterval(()=>{
  let date = new Date();
  let twoWeeks = 1.2096e+9 //2 weeks in milliseconds
  switch (Math.floor(((date - startDate)/twoWeeks)%4)) {
//difference between the dates, divide it by the twoWeeks number to get how many of
//that interval have passed, get the remainder from dividing by 4 in case more than
//8 weeks have passed, then floor it to get an integer
    case 1:
      function1();
      break;
    case 2:
      function2();
      break;
    case 3:
      function3();
      break;
    case 0: //will happen if it's happened 4 times or 0
      function4();
      break;
  }
}, y); //y is any interval in milliseconds, shorter will be more precise but will use more memory
```

if you want to prevent it from doing `function4()` before the first 2 week interval passes, you could update the function like so:

```js
window.setInterval(()=>{
  let date = new Date();
  let twoWeeks = 1.2096e+9;
  if ((date - startDate)/twoWeeks < 4) return;
  switch (Math.floor(((date - startDate)/twoWeeks)%4)) {
    case 1:
      function1();
      break;
    case 2:
      function2();
      break;
    case 3:
      function3();
      break;
    case 0:
      function4();
      break;
  }
}, y);
```

Note, this will have the functions be called more than once within that interval, but considering it's just setting which div will be visible, that won't be a problem.

Comment: Also I'd have the function determine which 14-day interval is currently in effect, then update a class on the `<body>` tag and use CSS to do all the display changes.

Comment: @Pointy I would probably do that too, but ik I get really annoyed when people add answers and give me unsolicited advice instead of just answering my question, so I just figured I'd answer the actual question and let OP do what they're doing otherwise

Comment: Well I appreciate your opinion, but on the other hand helping people carry out bad ideas isn't necessarily a good thing. Besides, the whole point of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of good answers to common questions.

Comment: Raphael Morgan, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is by using [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

The docs in that link explain it well but essentially you can set a date and time and pass in the function you'd want to call based on the given date/time params

```js
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  console.log('You will see this message every second');
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
job.start();
```

Comment: I don't think this applies to code in some random client web browser.

Comment: I'd personally render the results in a reactive way in the HTML and implement that logic on the server

Comment: What if the page is loaded in the client for 6 weeks?

Comment: Fair point. I guess we can set a timer to force a page reload or a button that renders through the front end asking the client to reload the page every 6 weeks